# Python get a list of years

Tags: python

I need to get the last 5 years in python. I was hoping to do this in once nice neat line. But the best i can come up with is this.

```
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
YEARS = [year, year-1, year-2, year-3, year-4, year-5]
```

Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can help:

```
>>> range(year, year - 6, -1)
[2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011]
```

Comment: Great answer, just a small remark, in python 3 use `list(range(year, year - 6, -1))`

Answer (score 8):

With a list comprehension:

```
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
YEARS = [year - i for i in range(6)]
```

or (in Python 2), just use `range()` directly to produce the list:

```
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
YEARS = range(year, year - 6, -1)
```

You can use the latter in Python 3 too, but you'll have to convert to a list with the `list()` call:

```
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
YEARS = list(range(year, year - 6, -1))
```

at which point the list comprehension may well be more readable. In all these expressions, you can inline the `datetime.datetime.today().year`, but this does mean it'll be called 6 times (for the list comprehension) or twice (for the `range()`-only approaches).

Answer (score 1):

```
 years_back = 5
 year = datetime.datetime.today().year
 YEARS = [year - i for i in range(years_back+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is, but it will be the same number of lines. You can use a list comprehension to generate the offsets so that you do not have to type them all manually. Especially useful if the number changes:

```
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
YEARS = [year - offset for offset in range(6)]
```

Note the `range(6)` since you are actually asking for a list of 6 items if you include this year (`year - 0`).

Answer (score -1):

You could use a list comprehension.

For example:

```
 years = [datetime.datetime.today().year - index for index in range(6)]
```

This loops through the numbers 0-5, and subtracts the number from this year.

Comment: This does call `datetime.datetime.today()` 5 times.

Comment: The five calls are necessary to get it into a single line as requested by the OP.  I'll fix the upper end of the range though (for later readers, it was originally `range(5)` instead of `range(6)`.